# Is it possible to attach a "tag" to a token object in Lua?

Tags: luatex

In Lua, a token object is represented by a `userdata` object.

I want to be able to give these tokens back to TeX, manipulate them a bit, then read them back with Lua; but after that I need to know which token comes from where.
.
For example:

```tex
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,margin=0.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{luacode}
%\usepackage{prettytok} \prettyN {}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\directlua{dofile "a.lua"}

\def\g{\directlua{g()}}
\def\swap #1 #2{\g #2 #1}
\use:n {
  \directlua{f()} \a \a
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Lua:

```lua
prettyprint=print

function f()
    local a=token.get_next()
    local b=token.get_next()
    prettyprint(a, b)
    prettyprint(a.tok, b.tok)  -- same token, .tok is the same
    prettyprint(a.id, b.id)  -- but id is different
    token.put_next({token.create("swap"), a, b})
    --a._tag=123  -- error: attempt to index a luatex.token value
end

function g()
    local a=token.get_next()
    local b=token.get_next()
    prettyprint(a, b)
    prettyprint(a.tok, b.tok)  -- same token, .tok is the same
    prettyprint(a.id, b.id)  -- unfortunately the id is different from the previous
end
```

As you can see, the `a` and `b` objects in `f` are the two `\a` tokens respectively, then it expands to `\swap \a1 \a2` → `\g \a2 \a1`. I want to "distinguish" the two `\a` here, i.e. tell if the `\swap` macro really swaps the two arguments or not.

Of course this is not 100% foolproof (e.g. if the TeX macro do `\cs_to_str:N` followed by `\use:c` then the tag would probably be lost anyway), but for this simple use case is there any solution (apart from reimplementing the token grabbing mechanism/input stream of TeX inside Lua)? (I tried tracking the `.id` value but it changes.)

<sub>background: use case, I'm implementing some kind of compiler that outputs TeX and I want to keep the tag data as the line number attached to each token, and I want to allow user to define macro that manipulates the code itself; but I don't know how to keep track of the line number in that case</sub>